# Spring JpaRepository ENUM mismatch

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-data-jpa, h2

My enum class is as follows:

```
public enum Sex {

    MALE('M'), FEMALE('F'), UNKNOWN('U');

    char name;

    Sex(char name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

My H2 database schema for the attribute is as follows:

`sex          CHAR(1),`

My model class is:

```
@Column
@NotNull
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Sex sex;
```

When I try to populate my models via `JpaRepository` I get an exception as follows:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.awesome.enumeration.Sex.M`

What is preventing me from mapping my DB to the enum?

Comment: BTW: the term here rather is `gender`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a custom converter for your enum :

```
@Converter
public class SexConverter implements AttributeConverter<Sex, Character> {


    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(Sex sex) {
        return sex.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Sex convertToEntityAttribute(Character dbData) {
        return Sex.getByName(dbData);
    }
}
```

Then in your entity :

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @Convert(converter = SexConverter.class)
    private Sex sex;
}
```

I also created helper static method on your enum to get enum by char name :

```
public enum Sex {

    MALE('M'), FEMALE('F'), UNKNOWN('U');

    char name;

    Sex(char name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Sex getByName(char name) {
        return Arrays.stream(Sex.values())
                .filter(sex -> sex.getName() == name)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(UNKNOWN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It tries to find a Enum with name M. Your enums are MALE, FEMAL and UNKNOWN. You could chane your enum to `M, F, U`

Comment: Ideally, I want my enums to be MALE, FEMALE etc, but mapped to chars when saving to DB. How can I accomplish that?